# how to load js with jquery load method

Tags: jquery, load

I've tried to use the jQuery load method to load JavaScript:

```
<div id="update"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#update').load('find.html .themes', function(data) { 
    $(this).find('.themes').css({"width":"100%", "margin":"auto"});
});   
</script>
```

My file find.html:

```
    <div class="themes">
      <script> document.write('This is a test'); </script>
    </div>
```

Please can someone show me how to load JavaScript?

Comment: `document.write` not a good idea to test.

Comment: I want to load all items that are covered with class name themes.

Comment: I need an example to understand the process,

Comment: Ya indeed when passing fragment url to `$.fn.load()` method, script are discarded, even part of fragment: `// If a selector was specified, locate the right elements in a dummy div
    // Exclude scripts to avoid IE 'Permission Denied' errors`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have much things in your `find.html` div then you can access all the elements directly:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#update').load('find.html', function(data) {
    $(this).find('.themes').css({
      "width": "100%",
      "margin": "auto"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should then use other ajax mehtod, e.g:

```
$.get('find.html', function(data) {
  $('#update').empty().append($('<div/>', {
    html: data
  }).find('.themes').css({
    "width": "100%",
    "margin": "auto"
  }));
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

`empty().append()` not `html()` which accepts only string (even you could pass object but it is not designed for it and <strike>can be</strike> *it is* buggy).

**PS:** Be aware in your case using `document.write()` would overwrite all `document` content, because this is how it works once document is fully parsed. So don't use it, even just for testing purpose.